# nginx cannot start on redhat server

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install nginx on a rhel 7 and it says process doesn't start. Following is the log.

> Nov 13 06:36:42 ip-10-0-0-10.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Starting nginx -
>   high performance web server...**
>
> Nov 13 06:36:42 ip-10-0-0-10.ec2.internal nginx[30974]: nginx: the
>   configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
>
> Nov 13 06:36:42 ip-10-0-0-10.ec2.internal nginx[30974]: nginx: [emerg]
>   open() "/mnt/nginx_logs/pubstore/access.log" failed (13: Permission
>   denied)
>
> Nov 13 06:36:42 ip-10-0-0-10.ec2.internal nginx[30974]: nginx:
>   configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
>
> Nov 13 06:36:42 ip-10-0-0-10.ec2.internal systemd[1]: nginx.service:
>   control process exited, code=exited status=1
>
> Nov 13 06:36:42 ip-10-0-0-10.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start
>   nginx - high performance web server.
>
> Nov 13 06:36:42 ip-10-0-0-10.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Unit
>   nginx.service entered failed state.**

The permission of the file access log is as follows. I have given permission but still it doesn't start.

-rwxrwxrwx. 1 nginx nginx 0 Nov 13 02:07 access.log

-rwxrwxrwx. 1 nginx nginx 0 Nov 13 02:07 error.log

The installation is done on a puppet agent on amazon ec2 instance

Answer (score 2):

This line:

> Nov 13 06:36:42 ip-10-0-0-10.ec2.internal nginx[30974]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/mnt/nginx_logs/pubstore/access.log" failed (13: Permission denied)

Tells you that the user you are running nginx as, does not have access to write to the log file its configured to write to.

Since the logs are being stored in a non-standard location, you will likely have to ensure that the directory you want to store logs in, is writable by the same user that nginx is running as.

Comment: rwxrwxrwx. 1 nginx nginx 0 Nov 13 02:07 access.log

-rwxrwxrwx. 1 nginx nginx 0 Nov 13 02:07 error.log.                                      these are the permission i have give to those files aren't they enough.. The folder that have those files also have same permissions..